# 2.82 shape key problem?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create a lower thirds seamless vid, using waving cloth physics.  However, after saving/applying the .mdd file/adding Mesh Cache modifiers/tweaking Influence, etc, it will not animate between frames 125-240?

Do I have the settings wrong:[image]